# OpenGL - Grid not connected

Tags: c++, opengl, grid

My code for creating my grid is:

```
    // Per-vertex position vectors
static float planeVertices[16] =
{
    0,1,0,1,
    0,0,0,1,
    1,1,0,1,
    1,0,0,1
};

    // 12 faces each with 3 vertices (each face forms a triangle) (36 indices total)
    static unsigned short planeVertexIndices[4] =
    {
        0,1,2,3   
    };
```

drawPlane:

```
    void drawPlane(float x, float y, float z){
        glUseProgram(planeShader);
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

        // Setup simple translation (model) matrix and pass to shader
        GUMatrix4 planeModelTransform = GUMatrix4::translationMatrix(x, y, z);

        static GLint planeShader_modelMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(planeShader, "modelMatrix");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(planeShader_modelMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&planeModelTransform);

        glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)1);

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

        //glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

How its drawn in update:

int gridSize = 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
float z = 0.0f;



for (float x = -gridSize/2; x < gridSize/2; x++){

    for (float y = -gridSize/2; y < gridSize/2; y++){

        drawPlane(x, y, z);
    }

}
```

The grid draws fine, but none of its connected as I want the grid to wave, when I make it wave you can see the triangles are all separate.

My vertex shader:

```
#version 330

uniform float waveTime;
uniform float waveWidth;
uniform float waveHeight;

// UBO to store the camera projection and view matrices
uniform CameraMatrixBlock {

    mat4 viewMatrix;
    mat4 projectionMatrix;

} cam;


uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

layout (location=0) in vec4 vertexPos;
layout (location=1) in vec4 vertexColour;

out vec4 vp;
out vec4 colour;

void main(void) {

    colour = vertexColour;
    vec4 vp = vertexPos;
    mat4 P = cam.projectionMatrix;
    mat4 V = cam.viewMatrix;

    mat4 mvpMatrix = P * V * modelMatrix;

    vp.z = sin(waveWidth * vp.x + waveTime) * cos(waveWidth * vp.y + waveTime) * waveHeight;

    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vp;


}
```

What the result I get from all this:
[The results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWgRm.png)

Comment: To draw the plane, you are getting `gridSize` and dividing by `2`. Since both of them are `int`, the result will be `int` as well. You can fix it by changing the calculation to result `float` (by casting one of them to float. e.g: `=gridSize/2.0`). Although, if everything works fine, there still be cases where the vertices will be disconnected (because of the precision and z-fighting). If that happens, you can fix by sharing vertex between triangles (e.g. re-using it on the index array).